# Backbone routes, what is the # tag?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm just starting on a web project that is already using Backbone  I haven't done any web until now.  I have been reading the documentation and reading up on routers (http://thomasdavis.github.com/2011/02/07/making-a-restful-ajax-app.html and http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/#/route/action), but I'm not sure if I understand one of the basic things.

What is the # tag used for with backbone routers?  I googled and saw that # was used to point to specific points in a page, but other than that, I'm not really sure how backbone uses it.  Like on this page: http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/#/route/action they say this:

```
Also note that routes interpret anything after "#" tag in the URL. All links in your application should target "#/action" or "#action". (Appending a forward slash after the hashtag looks a bit nicer e.g. http://example.com/#/user/help)
```

But what does that actually mean?  I don't quite get it.  Sorry for the noob question but I really couldn't figure it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The portion of a URL after the hash is the "[fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)" which was originally to reference an in-page anchor like http://example.com/my_long_article#Section-14 where that is a single HTML document with an `<a name="Section-14"></a>` just above the section 14 material. The browser doesn't actually send this portion of the URL to the server in requests (which can be frustrating), it's just used to auto-scroll a long document to that location.

For modern single page apps, this technology has been repurposed to get the URL to represent a particular screen or view within in application but without causing the browser to actually request a different document. So if you navigate from `/my-app#cars` to `/my-app#trucks`, the browser doesn't load a new page, which means your javascript stays loaded and can respond in the "single page" style.

Modern browsers can achieve this via the [HTML5 pushState API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html), but for older browsers, the hash approach is still common.